# why modifying value on one instance changes value at another?

Tags: javascript

Why does `foo.value` get changed in the example below?

```
var Zzz = function() {};

Zzz.prototype.foo = {};

Zzz.prototype.set = function (v) {
    this.foo.value = v;
};

var Z1 = new Zzz();
Z1.set(100);

var Z2 = new Zzz();
Z2.set(200);

console.log(Z1.foo, Z2.foo); // 200, 200
console.log(Z1 === Z2); // false
console.log(Z1.foo.value == Z2.foo.value); // true < WHY????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have an answer here, but in case you still doesn't understand.

`prototype` property of constructor is object where all instances will have properties that refer to properties of that object.

When you create new instance and ask about its property (`foo`), JS will first look at that instance and try to find *its own* property `foo`. If here is no `foo`, then JS will look at instance prototype and asks about `foo` there.

Code sample:

```
var Zzz = function() {};

Zzz.prototype.foo = {};

Zzz.prototype.set = function (v) {
    this.foo.value = v;
};

var Z1 = new Zzz();
Z1.set(100);

var Z2 = new Zzz();
Z2.set(200);

// but when we create new object only for Z1 instance
Z1.foo = {};
Z1.set(100); // this.foo in set function refers to that new object
console.log(Z1.foo, Z2.foo); // 100, 200

console.log(Z1.foo === Zzz.prototype.foo); // false
console.log(Z2.foo === Zzz.prototype.foo); // true
```

Also if you delete `foo` property later with:

```
delete Z1.foo;
console.log(Z1.foo === Zzz.prototype.foo); // is true again
```

When you need unique property for each instance, you *bind* it to this in constructor. When you need common property for all instances (like function set), you *bind* it to prototype. If you don't know, then properties from prototype can be always overridden later.

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation! Marking as an answer!

Answer (score 4):

Because `foo` is part of the prototype, it's like a static variable in languages like Java or PHP (and probably many others).

This means that changing the value on one of them will affect all instances of that class.

For individual instances, try:

```
var Zzz = function() {
    this.foo = {};
};
Zzz.prototype.set = function(v) {
    this.foo.value = v;
};
```

Comment: Damn, you're fast. +1